# OAuth 1 Callback url not working

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I'm trying to use Magento 1.X Rest Api with this [Oauth lib](https://github.com/sudocode/ohmy-auth).
But when I run the script, I'm getting stuck in this url:

```
http://myhost.com.br/admin/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=xxxxxx
```

The script doesn't go on after this step and doesn't come back to my localhost url. What should I do?

This is my script

```
$callbackUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = 'http://myhost.com.br/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=' . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://myhost.com.br/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://myhost.com.br/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://myhost.com.br//api/rest/products';
$consumerKey = 'consumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'consumersecret';

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use ohmy\Auth1;


Auth1::legs(3)
     ->set('key', $consumerKey)
     ->set('secret', $consumerSecret)
     ->set(array(
            'key'      => $consumerKey,
            'secret'   => $consumerSecret,
            'oauth_callback' => $callbackUrl
        ))
     ->request($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl)
     ->authorize($adminAuthorizationUrl)
     ->access($accessTokenRequestUrl)
     ->GET($apiUrl)
     ->then(function($response) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($response->json());
            echo '</pre>';
        });
```